# Change radio button colour and select first element on load

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to populate radio buttons with data from MySQL.

I'd like the selected radio button to change colour, and the first element to be selected on page load.

How can I do this?

```
<div class="panel bg-product">
  <?php
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM products");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($prod_id, $prod_name, $prod_price);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
      echo '<label><input type="radio" name="config-prod" value="'.$prod_id.'"> ' .$prod_name.'</label><br>';
    }
    $stmt->close();
  ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
  font-weight: 700;
  color: red;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

This CSS does not change the colour of the radio button when selected, nor is a radio button selected on load.

Comment: You cannot check a radiobutton with CSS. You can easily do it with javascript.

Comment: He is not checking an element with css. He is targeting to style the "checked element"

Comment: @Mosia nope, the question asks: "... and select first element on load"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your new CSS:

```
.input-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.input-list li input:checked{
  content: "";
      -webkit-appearance: push-button;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    height: 12px;
    background: red;
}

.input-list li input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

New JS code:

```
document.querySelector("#radio li input").checked = true;
```

And Your new PHP:

```
    <ul id="radio" class="input-list">
  <?php
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, name, price FROM products");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($prod_id, $prod_name, $prod_price);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
      echo '<li>
              <input id="'.$prod_id.'" name="config-prod" value="'.$prod_id.'" type="radio">
              <label class="sub-label" for="'.$prod_id.'">'.$prod_name.'</label>
            </li>';
    }
    $stmt->close();
  ?>
</ul>
```

And that's how it will look:

```js
document.querySelector("#radio li input").checked = true;
```

```css
.input-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.input-list li input:checked {
  content: "";
      -webkit-appearance: push-button;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    height: 12px;
    background: red;
}

.input-list li input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="radio" class="input-list">
  <li>
    <input id="first" name="radio" value="first" type="radio">
    <label class="sub-label" for="first">first</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="second" name="radio" value="second" type="radio">
    <label class="sub-label" for="second">second</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. However, this outputs {$prod_name} for each radio label, as opposed to the actual data from the DB.

Comment: I'm encountering a problem with this line: <label class="sub-label" for="{$prod_id}">{$prod_name}</label>. It outputs {$prod_name} not the value from the database.

Comment: I have edited the code in my answer, try the new version.

Comment: Why are you using JS to select the first input? I would have done that in the PHP rather than rely on client-side code.

Comment: In this way, reduce the server load. Besides, it's simpler. Of course, you can do it on the php page, if you want I will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you. But you must note that it colors the `label` and not the `radio`, I think this is what you were trying to achieve.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
  <input type="radio"  name="radios" /><label>R1</label> //label for first Radio
  <input type="radio" name="radios" /><label>R2</label> //Label for second radio
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Tested on Codepen and works. Just use this as a template and populate your data accordingly. Just used some `style` to make it visible as I test.